# plt doesn't change xticks, yticks, xlabel and ylabel to bold

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to convert xticks, yticks, xlabel and ylabel to bold, but nothing work. I attached a screenshot of the output graph.

```py
# visualize the loss as the network trained
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.plot(range(1,len(All_end_eopch_training_loss)+1),All_end_eopch_training_loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(range(1,len(All_end_eopch_validation_loss)+1),All_end_eopch_validation_loss,label='Validation Loss')

# find position of lowest validation loss
minposs = All_end_eopch_validation_loss.index(min(All_end_eopch_validation_loss))+1
plt.axvline(minposs, linestyle='--', color='r',label='Early Stopping Checkpoint')

mod_size = 20

plt.xlabel('epochs',fontsize=mod_size, fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel('loss', fontsize=mod_size, fontweight='bold')
plt.ylim(0,0.3) # consistent scale
plt.xlim(0, len(All_end_eopch_training_loss)+1) # consistent scale
plt.xticks(fontsize=mod_size)
plt.yticks(fontsize=mod_size)
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(fontsize=10)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
    
fig.savefig(f'LOSS_ACC_Files/{tensor_baord_variable}_loss_plot.pdf',format="pdf", dpi= 400, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you used LaTeX for all text in a figure. Perhaps you have set `matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)` before.

You can change xticks, yticks, xlabel and ylabel to bold by doing something like:

```
plt.rc('xtick', weight = 'bold')
plt.rc('ytick', weight = 'bold')
plt.xlabel(r'\textbf{epochs}')
plt.ylabel(r'\textbf{loss}')
```

Comment: Yes, this used after the above code as `plt.rcParams.update({ "text.usetex": True})`.

but I have an error when using your code:

`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Desktop/Barham/Conferance_Sign_Language_paper/conf_sign_lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in __setitem__(self, key, val)
    643             try:
--> 644                 cval = self.validate[key](val)
    645             except ValueError as ve:

KeyError: 'xtick.weight'
`

Comment: @Pain How about `plt.xticks(x, weight = 'bold')`?

Comment: xticks becomes more smaller, I tried to change the font weight, but nothing change.